# How to count number of social shares on web page locally

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I have a Facebook share button on a page, 
And now the user shares a post on his/her timeline, Now what i want to do is count the number of times that specific user shares it in that session.

For Example the count will be initialized to 0 for all users , What i want is Each time a person shares a post successfully the count to increment.

We create a variable count and initialize to 0, now the share button works fine, How can i increment the count each time the post is successfully shared? 
What variables would be needed and how can this be done?

```
<?php
session_start();
$fbcount = $_SESSION['count'];

function incrememnt() {
      $fbcount++;
 }
?>

<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would think you could do something in the function(response). The response should have some information in it about what happened with the call. Even a success flag of some sort hopefully. Then do something if it was successful, like call increment(). First thing I would do is console.log(response) and see what's in there.

Comment: @user1289451 It returns status code "200" when it is successful , Can you use that in some way to use the increment function with it? Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can. See my answer

Comment: Why would a user share the same post(?) multiple times? (Hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way, and neither to lock content behind a "forced" share.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact syntax without seeing the properties on the response object, but you should be able to do something like:

```
  document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
      FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
      }, function(response){
             if(response.statusCode == '200'){
                 increment();
             }    

      });
    }
```

You will likely have to change response.statusCode to whatever property you actually have on the response object.

This would also be a good place for error handling. Maybe throw an else after the if to do something if it's anything but 200.